# Refresh UltraCombo Content

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultracombo

I have to do some maintenance on an old VB.NET application (Visual Studio 2003) that uses Infragistics NetAdvantage 2006. I have a UltraCombo control binded to a DataView.

How can I refresh the content displayed after a change in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to repopulate the DataView from the database and refresh your databinding on the UltraCombo; probably pretty close to the same code you use to initially populate the DataView and set the UltraCombo databinding.

You may get a more complete answer if you post some code.